# Using ActiveRecord scope for calculation with multiple columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an `ActiveRecord` model that has two database attributes, `total` and `processing_fees`.

It has various scopes defined, such as (just as examples):

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :completed, joins(:order).where(:orders => {:status => Order::Status::COMPLETED})
  scope :for_client, lambda {|client| where("client_id=?", client.id)}
...etc...
end
```

I can easily do something like:

```
Item.completed.for_client(client).sum(:total)
```

but what I would like to do is something like:

```
Item.completed.for_client(client).calculate(:total - :processing_fees) # obv not valid
```

Is there any way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Item.completed.for_client(client).calculate(:sum, "item.total - item.processing_fees")
```

Comment: Well, *that* was easy.  Didn't occur to me that you could put an expression in there.  Seems to me maybe the doc needs to be updated, since it says:

`calculate(operation, column_name, options = {})
This calculates aggregate values in the given column.`

Comment: @dwhsix: documentation is sometimes a bit thin on such things. Rails quite often allows to drop in a piece of sql in such places. And in general often takes different kinds of parameters like hashes or arrays where the basic documentation only talks about a single symbol for a field name. And that's not only for ActiveRecord. Some of the helpers are good examples for methods taking lots of different input.

Comment: Agreed.  I actually looked at the doc again a bit more closely, intending to maybe provide an edit to it.  It does have a *final* brief example that shows you can use a SQL expression, but it's a little subtle.  I think maybe doc needs to say "column_name or SQL expression" or something like that.  I'll try to remember to make that change somewhere in the doc.